# Proving the (in)tractability of this Nth prime recurrence

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, recurrence-relation, mathematical-analysis

As follows [from my previous question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1828/polytime-and-polyspace-algorithm-for-determining-the-leading-intersection-of-n-d), I've been playing with the [Riemann hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis) as a matter of recreational mathematics. In the process, I've come to a rather interesting recurrence, and I'm curious as to its name, its reductions, and its tractability towards the solvability of the gap between prime numbers.

Tersely speaking, we can define the *gap* between each prime number as a recurrence of preceding *candidate* primes. For example, for our base of $p_0 = 2$, the next prime would be:

$\qquad \displaystyle p_1 = \min \{ x > p_0 \mid -\cos(2\pi(x+1)/p_0) + 1 = 0)  \}$

Or, as we see by [plotting this out](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-cos%28%28x%2b1%29*2*pi/2%29%20%2b%201%20=%200): $p_1 = 3$.

We can repeat the process for $n$ primes by evaluating each candidate prime recurring forward. Suppose we want to get the next prime, $p_2$. Our candidate function becomes:

$\qquad \displaystyle \begin{align}
p_2 = \min\{ x > p_1 \mid f_{p_1}(x) + (&(-\cos(2\pi(x+1)/p_1) + 1) \\
                                   \cdot &(-\cos(2\pi(x+2)/p_1) + 1)) = 0\}
\end{align}$

Where:

$\qquad \displaystyle f_{p_1}(x) = -\cos(2\pi(x+1)/p_0) + 1$, as above.

It's easy to see that each component function only becomes zero on integer values, and it's equally easy to show how this captures our AND- and XOR-shaped relationships cleverly, by exploiting the properties of addition and multiplication in the context of a system of trigonometric equations.

The recurrence becomes:

$\qquad f_{p_0} = 0\\
\qquad p_0 = 2\\
\qquad \displaystyle
  f_{p_n}(x) = f_{p_{n-1}}(x) + \prod_{k=2}^{p_{n-1}} (-\cos(2\pi(x+k-1)/p_{n-1}) + 1)\\
 \qquad \displaystyle
 p_n = \min\left\{ x > p_{n-1} \mid f_{p_n}(x) = 0\right\}$

... where the entire problem hinges on whether we can evaluate the $\min$ operator over this function in polynomial time. This is, in effect, a generalization of the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Working Python code to demonstrate the recurrence:

```
from math import cos,pi

def cosProduct(x,p):
    """ Handles the cosine product in a handy single function """
    ret = 1.0
    for k in xrange(2,p+1):
        ret *= -cos(2*pi*(x+k-1)/p)+1.0
    return ret

def nthPrime(n):
    """ Generates the nth prime, where n is a zero-based integer """

    # Preconditions: n must be an integer greater than -1
    if not isinstance(n,int) or n < 0:
        raise ValueError("n must be an integer greater than -1")

    # Base case: the 0th prime is 2, 0th function vacuous
    if n == 0:
        return 2,lambda x: 0

    # Get the preceding evaluation
    p_nMinusOne,fn_nMinusOne = nthPrime(n-1)

    # Define the function for the Nth prime
    fn_n = lambda x: fn_nMinusOne(x) + cosProduct(x,p_nMinusOne)

    # Evaluate it (I need a solver here if it's tractable!)
    for k in xrange(p_nMinusOne+1,int(p_nMinusOne**2.718281828)):
        if fn_n(k) == 0:
            p_n = k
            break

    # Return the Nth prime and its function
    return p_n,fn_n
```

A quick example:

```
>>> [nthPrime(i)[0] for i in range(20)]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71]
```

The trouble is, I'm now in way over my head, both mathematically and as a computer scientist. Specifically, I am not competent with [Fourier analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis), with defining [uniform covers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space#Uniform_cover_definition), or with the [complex plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane) in general, and I'm worried that this approach is either flat-out *wrong* or hides a lurking horror of a 3SAT problem that elevates it to NP-completeness.

Thus, I have three questions here:

> 1. Given my terse recurrence above, is it possible to deterministically compute or estimate the location of the zeroes in polynomial time and space?
> 2. If so or if not, is it hiding *any other* subproblems that would make a polytime or polyspace solution intractable?
> 3. And if by some miracle (1) and (2) hold up, what dynamic programming improvements would you make in satisfying this recurrence, from a high level? Clearly, iteration over the same integers through multiple functions is inelegant and quite wasteful.

Comment: And for those still here in spite of my wall of text: I'm _unsure_ if this reduces itself to the Riemann zeta, thereby giving it the same complexity. I don't believe it does, though.

Comment: 1) What tags would you like? You can create them yourself by just using them. 2) Please give a general definition for $f$, i.e. what is $f(p_n)$? 3) If you don't get an answer on this after a week or so, you might want to move it so cstheory.SE.

Comment: I am not following everything in your post. I guess you mean NP-complete not NP. Generally proving that a number theoretic function is NP-complete is quite difficult task since they often lack/hide any combinatorial structure that would allow us to design gadgets for the reduction.

Comment: Revision complete. There are sure to be other lurking issues, but my original representation was quite off the mark. I should consult with my 24-hours-younger self and give him a refresher on proper definitions of $f(x)$. In any case, thank you for your patience and your edits so far. The current tags are also now to my satisfaction. :)

Comment: Regarding $f$, is it not sufficient to "check" all smaller primes as opposed to all smaller numbers?

Comment: @Raphael I see what you implied by your first edit, now that you've called it out! I believe that will hold true, but I'll want to double-check when I'm less sleepy. If true, that will significantly reduce the growth of the function overhead of this recurrence, which is quite nice.

Comment: @Raphael I could be very wrong, but I believe the adversarial case, solving $p_5 = 13$, causes your prime-iterating formulation to break down. Similarly, I find myself greatly worried that _my_ version false-positives for some adversarial case, possibly as simple as some set of odd terms. I haven't punched a hole in it successfully yet, though. Again, thank you sincerely for your help so far.

Comment: Added working code in Python to my question, including _exactly_ where the (root?) solver is necessary. I tested it for the first 100 primes on my end; they seem to match up.

Comment: you seem to be investigating building an algorithm to compute the differences between successive primes. this is indeed highly related to the Riemann fn probably.... but was not able to follow your analysis. it would prob help if you plotted something about how it works for more than a few primes..... meantime yes, this is more of a number theory question. also note that many problems related to the complexity of factoring & computing primes are open....

Comment: What is the line p_nMinusOne**2.718281828 for?

Answer (score 1):

The following paper shows that PRIMES is in P (it also won a Gödel award in 2006):

http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/algebra/primality_v6.pdf

By setting the solution of the Nth prime minimization procedure to the AKS PRIMES algorithm (modulo a subtraction), we may effectively get a tractable solution to the recurrence relation (if you can prove that the prime gap is given by the recurrence relation).

Source codes can be found on the internet. I am not pointing to them here because I did not check them personally.

As is however, we may still have the upper bound of $\sqrt{n}$ for checking all numbers...

Comment: The Rosettacode page is completely mis-named.  This is not the AKS primality test, and is a restatement of trial division by all integers less than n.  On the other hand, noting that primality is in P and seeing if that sheds any light on the original question is worth asking.

Comment: Good point... I'll fix that...

Comment: Primes in P doesn't imply that we can generate prime numbers deterministically in polynomial time. It is a hard open problem. ($\sqrt{n}$ is an exponential functions in the size of the input which is $\lg n$.)