# Complexity of computer algebra for systems of trigonometric equations

Tags: reference-request, runtime-analysis, mathematical-analysis, computer-algebra, mathematical-software

[As discussed in this question,](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1984/proving-the-intractability-of-this-nth-prime-recurrence) I drafted a spec algorithm that hinges on finding a specific root of a system of trigonometric equations satisfying the following recurrence:

$\qquad f_{p_0} = 0\\
\qquad p_0 = 2\\
\qquad \displaystyle
  f_{p_n}(x) = f_{p_{n-1}}(x) + \prod_{k=2}^{p_{n-1}} (-\cos(2\pi(x+k-1)/p_{n-1}) + 1)\\
 \qquad \displaystyle
 p_n = \min\left\{ x > p_{n-1} \mid f_{p_n}(x) = 0\right\}$

[Playing with this system a bit over on Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%92cos%282%CF%80%28x%2b1%29/2%29%2b1%2b%28%E2%88%92cos%282%CF%80%28x%2b1%29/3%29%2b1%29%28%E2%88%92cos%282%CF%80%28x%2b2%29/3%29%2b1%29%2b%28%E2%88%92cos%282%CF%80%28x%2b1%29/5%29%2b1%29%28%E2%88%92cos%282%CF%80%28x%2b2%29/5%29%2b1%29%28%E2%88%92cos%282%CF%80%28x%2b3%29/5%29%2b1%29%28%E2%88%92cos%282%CF%80%28x%2b4%29/5%29%2b1%29=0%20for%20x), it seems I can get specific answers to the recurrence from their [computer algebra system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system). Unfortunately, I can find no specific documentation on the methods they're using to solve my equations.

My question, then:

> What methods (and what time and space complexities) do computer algebra systems use to solve these forms of equations? I suspect the [Gröbner basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis) is commonly used, but I could be very wrong.

Comment: Good question! If you don't get an answer here, your might want to visit [mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com). Please wait a few days, though, because crossposting is generally frowned upon.

Comment: There are open source computer algebra packages around, like http://maxima.sourceforge.net. One possible technique is to just express everything in terms of $\tan \theta$, which reduces trignometric expressions to a "simple" algebraic problem to munge.